# Homologación de una base de datos

Tags: rstudio, code-first

yo he estado tratando de homologar una base de datos con respecto a otra las cuales debo cruzar al final del ejercicio. Lo que ocurre es que las variables numérica no son las mismas en ambas bases o sea no tiene coincidencias. Como debería realizalo si una de la base a cruzar solo tiene el código de compra el producto y la otra me tiene la información. Alguien sabe cómo es la mejor manera de hacerlo o debo buscar por el nombre? Estoy usando rstudio.